# Quelle est la désignation de la personne qui sert dans un restaurant?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Dans un restaurant, dit-on encore « garçon » pour s'adresser à la personne qui nous sert, ou dit-on autre chose? Aussi, que serait son féminin, comme « waitress » est le féminin de « waiter » en anglais?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le terme *garçon* a vieilli dans cet emploi, il existe toujours mais tend à devenir plus rare au fur et à mesure.

Pour interpeler le serveur ou la serveuse d'un restaurant, on aura le plus souvent recours à une locution permettant d'éviter la référence directe :

> « S'il vous plait ! » *(ou parfois)* « Excusez-moi... »

qui signifie que l'on réclame l'attention de la personne, mais qui reste court, neutre et courtois.

Mais en effet il arrive aussi qu'on emploie, selon le genre, *Garçon*, *Monsieur*, ou *Mademoiselle*.

A noter aussi : **en aucun cas on n'emploie *serveur* ou *serveuse* pour interpeler** la personne, ce n'est qu'une désignation de leur métier.

Comment: Et on évite "Mademoiselle", en préférant un "Madame" plus générique.

Comment: @ElenaMellor Ne prends pas mon témoignage pour une prescription. On entend nettement plus *Mademoiselle* que *Madame* aujourd'hui, mais en effet comme tu le soulignes, l'usage du mot en lui-même tend à disparaitre au profit du plus générique *Madame*, et ça me va très bien ;-)

Answer (score 0):

« Garçon » est un bon terme quand la personne qui nous sert est un garçon. Sinon, le terme générique (et la traduction littérale de *waiter*) est « serveur » (celui qui sert), « serveuse » au féminin.